# Правильно задать директорию для FirefoxProfile

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
FirefoxDriverService ds = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
ds.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
opt.Profile = new FirefoxProfile(@"C:\111\");
IWebDriver Wd = new FirefoxDriver(ds, opt);
```

Пробовал так, но после запуска инстанса "C:\111\" продолжает быть пустой. Я хочу чтоб в этой папке сохранялись куки, кеш, расширения...

FirefoxOptions.Profile.ProfileDirectory - этот доступен только для чтения получается, как его установить - непонятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сначала создаем профиль
2. А потом уже используем как в примере кода в самом вопросе.

Для создания профиля запусти фаярфокс с префиксом -P (это нужно делать когда все инстансы браузера закрыты)

```
firefox.exe -P
```